# Error in stat_summary(fun.y) when plotting outliers in a modified ggplot-boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot boxplots showing the 95 percentile instead of the IQR, including outliers as defined by exceeding the 95% criterion.
This code is working fine, and based on several answers found here and on the web:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  subset(x, x < quantile(x, probs=0.025)) # only for low outliers
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}
d <- data.frame(x=gl(2,50), y=rnorm(100))

library(ggplot2)

p0 <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
        stat_summary(fun.data = f2, geom="boxplot") + coord_flip()

p1 <- p0 + stat_summary(fun.y = f1, geom="point")
```

The structure of d is:

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ y: num  2.275 0.659 -0.821 -0.129 1.997 ...
```

Now, coming to my real data, which is structured essentially the same:

```
str(test)
'data.frame':   11830917 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Ord.factor w/ 34 levels "SG26"<"SG22"<..: 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ y: num  84.6 84.1 93.3 84 93.2 94.3 83.3 92.5 94.5 98.8 ...
```

Now, if i am applying the same plot command, i get:

```
    p0 <- ggplot(test, aes(x,y)) + stat_summary(fun.data = f2, geom="boxplot") +  coord_flip() 
    p1 <- p0 + stat_summary(fun.y = f1, geom="point")
    p1

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen: 1, 0
```

The final line is the german version of "arguments imply differing number of rows 1 0". p0 is produced just fine.

What could be the difference between the two datasets?

Comment: Are you looking to modify the whisker length using the `coef` argument to `geom_boxplot()`?

Comment: I am not sure, how to do that, but yes, in the end, my whiskers should be defined be the 5 and 95% percentiles instead of the  default 1.5 IQR criterion.

Comment: I've tested your code with the `iris` dataset and I can't reproduce your error. I've tried adding NAs to the y-variable, and removing the y-values for an entire factor level. Without being able to reproduce the error I could only speculate about hidden value or features of your data. As a troubleshooting step, I would suggest computing all the quantiles for each factor level outside ggplot, into a separate data.frame. Then you can plot using this syntax: `geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=, lower=, middle=, upper=, ymax=))`

Comment: Could it be that there are x-variables with only one observation? I could replicate your error when I added a level '3' with one observation to the dataset. Look at the output of `f1(1)`.

Comment: As noted by @Heroka, the error can be reproduced with a dataset where a factor level has only one value. For example: `p <- ggplot(iris[1:51, ], aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Length)) + stat_summary(fun.data = f2, geom="boxplot") + coord_flip() + stat_summary(fun.y = f1, geom="point")`

Comment: You are perfectly right. There is one factor level with one observation, which shouldnt be there at all. I will try to remove that level once i am back in the office. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as identified by @Heroka and @bdemarest, arose by one factor level having only one value.

My workaround is to skip those factors:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 7) {
    return(subset(x, x < quantile(x, probs=0.025))) # only for low outliers
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
```

For unknown reasons, the problem persisted until there were at least 7 values per factor level.

Comment: Nice. Are you sure the current prob is right for the outliers? Don't you need c(0.025,0.975)? Your current approach only identifies the low outliers.

Comment: I want to look at the interval in which 95% of all values reside, which means, Yes, you are right, i need to look at 2.5 -> 97.5. Thank you for pointing it out. Ill change accordingly.